# Unable to reach the requested number of requests while running jmeter distributed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am working with 1 master, 50 slaves. Number of threads: 20
I have 1 thread and there are 3 samples in it. I'm starting the tests, but as a result of the test, I see that you are going 500-700 requests.

1000 requests from each should go. But it doesn't go.

Answer (score 0):

You have 20*50=1000 threads in total.

You can reach 1000 requests per second only if response time is 1 second sharp.

If response time will be 0.5 seconds - you will get 2000 requests per second

If response time will be 2 seconds - you will get 500 requests per second.

If you need to simulate X requests per second you need to add more threads (or alternatively go for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) combination)

But remember that the application under test **must be able to respond fast enough** because if it doesn't - any JMeter tweaks won't make any difference.

By the way, 1000 requests can be simulated from a modern mid-range laptop without any issues (unless your requests are "very heavy"), just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try again using Concurrency Thread Group and Throughput Shaping Timer.